# How to sort rows within a group (in descending order) using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below:

```
col1=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
col2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
col3=[1,2,3,2,3,1,3,1,2]
d={
    "col1":col1,
    "col2":col2,
    "col3":col3
}
dummy= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

So, the dataframe looks like below:

[image: dummy data]

I want to group all the values according to col1 and get values of col2 according to the sorting(decreasing ord) of col3, i.e, I want my end result as:
col2= [c,b,a,e,d,f,g,i,h]
I have tried the below which resits in col2 sorted in ascending order:

```
res=dummy.groupby(['col1','col3'])['col2'].apply(sorted).reset_index()
```

But the above results in [[a],[b],[c]....]]. I don't want each element to be a list in itself. How do I reverse the order? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use groupby here, a simple `sort_values` on the two columns will suffice:

```
dummy.sort_values(['col1', 'col3'], ascending=[True, False])

   col1 col2  col3
2     1    c     3
1     1    b     2
0     1    a     1
4     2    e     3
3     2    d     2
5     2    f     1
6     3    g     3
8     3    i     2
7     3    h     1
```

The order for "col2" is correct, you just need to return it as a list now:

```
col2_list = (dummy.sort_values(['col1', 'col3'], ascending=[True, False])
                  .get('col2')
                  .tolist())

col2_list
# ['c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'h']
```

---

In response to a request in the comments:

> now I want to combine these col2 values with col1 values, can I
> directly fetch col1 from dummy df and sorted col2 to create a new
> dataframe?
>
> The output should look like (eg): 1 [c,b,a] 2 [e,d,f] ...

Here we can build on the previous solution with `Groupby.agg` to listify the data:

```
(dummy.sort_values(['col1', 'col3'], ascending=[True, False])
      .groupby('col1', sort=False)['col2']
      .agg(list)
      .reset_index())

   col1       col2
0     1  [c, b, a]
1     2  [e, d, f]
2     3  [g, i, h]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just had one query, after getting the sorted values of col2, can I directly associate these values with col1? Meaning, now I want to combine these col2 values with col1 values, can I directly fetch col1 from dummy df and sorted col2 to create a new dataframe?

Comment: @Aditya I don't follow, sorry. Do you mean you want to get the col1 values that correspond to sorted col2 values as well? What should the output look like, list of tuples?

Comment: @ca95 The output should look like (eg): 
1  [c,b,a]
2  [e,d,f]
...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['col1'])[['col2','col3']].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('col3',ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)['col2']
```

Prints:

```
0    c
1    b
2    a
3    e
4    d
5    f
6    g
7    i
8    h
```

To print as a list use `series.tolist()`